# Cloudant: How to retrieve attachments from multiple documents?

Tags: java, couchdb, cloudant, nosql

Looking at the [Cloudant Java Client](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant), there are several examples regarding retrieving a single document's attachments, for example:

```
Foo foo = db.find(Foo.class, "exampleId", new Params().attachments());
String attachmentData = foo.getAttachments().get("attachment.txt").getData();
```

but no examples that I see for returning attachments from multiple documents in one call. [Search API](https://docs.cloudant.com/search.html) also doesn't mention anything about it.

The purpose of retrieving multiple attachments at once would be of course to avoid making multiple unnecessary network calls.

Any idea what the recommended way to retrieve more than one attachment per network call is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloudant Java client doesn't provide a way to get attachments for multiple documents in one network call because neither Cloudant or CouchDB provide an API to achieve it.

Comment: In practice does this turn out to be problematic for developers or is the use-case not as common as I would imagine when using Cloudant?

Comment: fwiw your the first I've seen that asks about this kind of function for the java Cloudant Client. Otherwise I don't really know how common a use case this is.